# USB Front Panel issues?

Tags: usb, motherboard, connection, front-panel

On my PC case I have built-in USB Front Panel, which is connected to motherboard. For such "small tasks" like connecting USB Stick and copying files - it works well. But when, for example, I connect my TomTom Start 25 Navigation device - it doesn't get recognized - Windows does not notice anything like it would not be connected at all. But when I connect the same device to USB port on motherboard - it gets recognized properly and works as it should (Win7 notices it, installs drivers properly).

Is there something wrong with my USB Front Panel or maybe its somehow wrong (if this possible at all) connected to motherboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most front panel connectors are 'dumb' breakout boards connected to the motherboard - they're a standardised connector attached to a header on one end, and the ports on the other. They are fairly idiotproof - since they can often only be plugged in one orientation. Plugging them in wrongly will result in the ports not working at all, or the pins on the motherboard side getting bent.

However, sometimes, they may not supply enough power for some devices ([lots of mentions of this](https://www.google.com/search?q=front%20panel%20usb%20insufficient%20power&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) on google, but insufficient objective citations on it, its common but no one seems to know why precisely) - your navigation device might be one of these.